# Write zeros in memory through a buffer overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

Trying to give a command line program an address to overwrite a return address saved in the stack. I could successfully overflow the input argument into the exact return address position but the address I want to give contains zeros (starts with with zeros eg `0x0000555555554bce`).

I give the address in from of string, the 00 must be a NUL character (`\0`) but I can't give that using the command line. Any idea on how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the problem has to do with packing your input. You can use any scripting language to pack your input. For example in [python](https://www.python.org/) you can do (*assuming x64-bit arch*):

```
cat <(python -c 'from pwn import p64; print your_padding_here + p64(0x555555554bce)') - | ./your_program
```

or if for any reason you prefer only built-in modules:

```
cat <(python -c 'print your_padding_here + __import__("struct").pack("I", 0x555555554bce)') - | ./your_program
```

Also you can accomplish the same thing by writing the buffer to a file and then pass the file as input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Well I used perl to do the same thing basically using 
`perl -e 'print "x\ce\x4b\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00"x10' `
but the problem is that no matter what i use the `"\x00"` Byte is a `NUL` character and it doesn't get printed!

Comment: Thats the memory content before the overflow i want to overwrite the address in the right:
`0x7fffffffdd50: 0x00007fffffffdd90      0x000055555555488e`
And this is it after the overflow:
`0x7fffffffdd50: 0x00007fffffffdd90      0x5555555555554bce`

Comment: hm..., maybe it has to do with stack alignment, are sure you have found the correct offset to overwrite that certain address ? I've had the same issue once with format-string exploit and I had used wrong padding...

Comment: well in 32bits architecture it's easy because addresses are 4 bytes long. you get no extra zeros in the end, I always get it to work. But in this case addresses are 6 bytes long so you always get two extra bytes that need to get a NUL character in order to make it align perfectly. 

I guess I'll take some time out and learn about this before trying buffer overflows in 64bit architectures. Anyway thanks a lot for your answers @game0ver it was valuable.

Comment: You are welcome!! Well in x64 bit, addresses are actually 8 bytes long (*not 6*) and also there are some other differences (*like in how syscalls are performed and how arguments are passed etc...*) but if you are familiar with 32 bit arch it won't be difficult to learn x64 also. Anyway I hope I've been of some help!

Comment: I have only 6 GB of ram probably that's why my addresses always end with 0x0000 (even the stack). thanks for the hint